# How to make all editors use the same images?

Tags: mailing, mosaico, images, directory, editor

I've decided to get my images in order in our CiviCRM installation under Joomla so that we can use the same images in mailings, articles and events. We are using Mosaico as the Mailing editor so there seems to be two aspects to handle.

1. How the get Mosaico to insert images from other folders than its own gallery
2. How to "unify" the various image directories:

- Joomla articles and media save images under `/images` (nice and simple...)
- CiviCRM directories recommendation are to use "images" without any variables, for Joomla this evaluates to `/media/civicrm/images/images` (strange but true), and this is where the CiviCRM editor places files, at least the CKEditor 4, for e.g. Event descriptions
- Mosaico is using `/media/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/uploads` where it creates files with randomised names for the ones you upload

A first step would be to have Joomla articles and the CiviCRM editor use the same directory.

I have fiddled with creating various symbolic links but I don't feel that is a robust solution.

I would appreciate any ideas or experiences.

Comment: Since it's been almost a year, did you find a solution or workaround? I'm dealing with a similar pain point (Joomla + Civi + Mosaico) and it leads to having to upload the same image in multiple places.

Comment: No solution, sorry. I tried working around it using directory links but that became messy since we already had a lot of images that were live, so I’m living with it for now.

Comment: I suspected as much, but one can always hope! I really hope there will be a solution to this at some point.